# Reading file using shell script, format of the line has changed

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

I am reading a file using the following code:

```
displayLine(){
    echo $line
}

filename="SampleFile"
while read line
do
    displayLine $line
done < "$filename"
```

The format of the file that I am getting after using the script is this:

```
ID EVENT OK NOK
101 ABC1123 ok nok
101 ABC1223 ok      
101 ABC1323 ok nok
101 ABC1423 ok nok
```

But the actual format of the file is like this:

```
ID  EVENT       OK      NOK
101 ABC1123     ok      nok
101 ABC1223     ok      
101 ABC1323     ok      nok
101 ABC1423     ok      nok
```

My script is somehow trimming the extra spaces between the words. However, I want the actual format of the file.

Could anyone tell me how to achieve that?

Thanks!!

Comment: why do you need a separate function to `echo` one thing ?

Comment: The function is suppose to do something else. But for the time being I am using it for echo.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/38906

Answer (score 1):

Quote your variables and use `IFS=` with read, as this:

```
displayLine(){ printf '%s\n' "$line"; }

filename="infile"

while IFS= read -r line
do
    displayLine "$line"
done < "$filename"
```